# M1 Xcode Launched App is frozen with DebugServer hogging the process

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-m1, rosetta

When I compile my app on Xcode and run it on normal Intel MacBook Pro, all good.
However, when run it on M1 MacBook Pro, I got the error on the console

`rosetta error: mmap_anonymous_rw_guard_page mprotect failed`

And then the App keeps frozen on the Launching Screen in the Simulator.

If I see the Activity Monitor, it has `debugserver` hogging the machine (as shown in diagram below). I kill it, then the App will die.

But I can relaunch the App from the simulator, and all is good. It's just that I have no way debugging the App on the Simulator. How can I get this issue fixed on M1?

[image]

Comment: have you tried starting the app in the simulator and then attaching debugger?

Comment: hi, do you have any update on this issue? Thank you!